# Refresh object references of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working on a heavily javascript based site with multiple language settings. The languages are stored in an external file, f e `app.en.js` and `app.de.js`. Both of these define the `lang` Object:

```
lang = {
    introText0 : 'Lorem',
    introText1 : 'Ipsum',
    introText2 : 'Dolor'
}
```

Now i have a function responsible for changing the language:

```
function changeLanguage(language) {
     delete lang;
     if(language === 1) { $.getScript('app.en.js'); }
     if(language === 2) { $.getScript('app.de.js'); }
}
```

So far so good. This works in theory. All over the app are references to the `lang` Object, replacing every text. Every text that gets referenced is being updated by this change, however, there are arrays that also refer to these, and they don't update properly.

```
var upgradeItems = new Array();
upgradeItems[0] = new Array(lang.upgradeItem0, 13, 5, true);
```

I take it that the garbage Collection of JavaScript only actually deletes unreferred properties of an Object, and since these got referred before the `changeLanguage()` happened, they stay in the app. How do i work around this and 'refresh' these Arrays?

Comment: can you give an example or clarify exactly what is not refreshing?

Comment: @webkit Once i refer to `upgradeItems[0][0]`, the old lang object is still in use. The array got defined before the language was changed, and it still refers to the old object.